# PS v.7 Select-String -Raw parameter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: powershell

I am searching for the string below in a .txt log file, but it outputs extra information. I read that PSv7 solved this issue with the -Raw parameter, but I am still getting extra information. When running PSv5, I would get the path in addition to the below, but now the -Raw has eliminated the path, but kept some other information from the same line the string is on.

What I am looking for:

```
An error occurred stopping transcription
```

What I get:

```
<![LOG[Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.]LOG]!><time="17:02:46.072+300" date="12-10-2021" component="RunPowerShellScript" context="" type="3" thread="8436" file="main.cpp:76">
```

The subset of my code:

```
Select-String -Path C:\somepath\log.txt -SimpleMatch "An error occurred stopping transcription" -Raw
```

I am try to follow up with a:

```
if ($errorcode -match $retrieveError) {
```

But, I can't match without the string matching the output.

Ugh

Comment: If your log file is XML (it appears that way) I would recommend loading it as XML and using XPath to search/extract data from it.

Comment: I'm not following on what the issue is, `Select-String` found the __line__ where the sentence "An error occurred" is. The result is the expected.

Comment: Using `-SimpleMatch` means you have no data in the `Matches` property of the matched object. When you use `-Raw`, you return only strings (entire matching string) rather than `MatchInfo` objects removing even more usable properties. So if you want to just return the same string you are matching, then just use an `if` statement around your `Select-String` and only process more code when there's a match.

Comment: My .00000046 BTC advice is to drop the `-Raw` and then just pipe to `Foreach-Object { }`. If you want the matched text only, then `$_.Pattern` inside of the `{ }`. If you want the whole matched line/string, then use `$_.Line`. For matched file path, `$_.Path`. For matched line number, `$_.LineNumber`. Or simply `$_` for the standard `Select-String` output. Then you can build a string output having whatever parts you like.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks for the guidance, it helped. The end code is: ```(Select-String -Path $logfiledest -SimpleMatch $errorcode).Pattern```. However, I just dont really understand why. What is ```().anythinghere``` do exactly? I've used it since the beginning and don't know what its called or its meaning. Also, how can I tell what I can use in that scenario? I've passed properties all day long, but ```().Pattern``` or ```().Path``` is new to me

Comment: @My9to5 The syntax `(code).anything` is member access. The code within `()` is an expression and is evaluated before the `.anything` notation is applied. `(code)` expression will return an object and if that object contains a `anything` property, then you will see the value of that property. `.Pattern` works here because you are returning a `MatchInfo` object that contains that property. If you use `-Raw`, then you return object type `String` and therefore do not have a `Pattern` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AdminofThings answered below. It is:

`(Select-String -Path $logfiledest -SimpleMatch $errorcode).Pattern`